# Line Graph in django template

Tags: python, django

To be very honest, I've played with matplotlib a little but iam new to django.
I have wandered all over google to search to plot a line graph in django using csv.
Unfortunately i couldnt find anything apart from 'bokeh' and 'chartit'. Although they arent very useful to help me make a start.

*My Goal:* I need to plot a line graph, where x-axis have dates, y-axis have some numbers.
Now, what should my views.py look like? What thing should i include in template?

Anyone please help me out, or send me some provide some video tutorial to start with

Comment: Why were they "not very useful to help you make a start"? You'll typically render a plot in your webapp using a JS library, not some static image

Comment: I was looking for something with example to render with csv file, but couldnt found as expected. I would love to walk through some links, if you some some.

Answer (score 0):

as pointed out by @roganjosh, you'll render the graph using a js library.
So in the views.py you'll have to add your data to the context, and then render it in the template using a js library. I personally like plotly.js, they have a neat and easy to use interface. D3.js is also a very popular data visualisation library.